# Как организовать методы в классе, чтобы их не было видно в подсказках?

Tags: java, eclipse, методы, область-видимости

Скажите пожалуйста, как надо переписать, чтобы методы `switchPlayersSkipIsEnabled()` и `switchPlayersActions()` не показывались в контекстной подсказке при написании кода в классе?
Два этих метода используются исключительно в этом месте, и не нужны больше нигде.

```
private void switchPlayersInterface() {
        currentPlayer.switchButtonsVisibility();
        mainPanel.enableMouseListeners();
        switchPlayersSkipIsEnabled();
        switchPlayersActions();
    }

        private void switchPlayersSkipIsEnabled() {
            player_1.switchSkipIsEnabled();
            player_2.switchSkipIsEnabled();
        }

        private void switchPlayersActions(){
            if (playerOneAction.isEnabled()){
                playerOneAction.setEnabled(false);
                playerTwoAction.setEnabled(false);
            }else{
                playerOneAction.setEnabled(true);
                playerTwoAction.setEnabled(true);
            }
```

[image: Пример]

Comment: Я бы просто переименовал их в что-нибудь вроде ``z_switch...`` и все, раз больше нигде не нужны.

Comment: Они показываются только внутри класса или в любом месте программы?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov внутри класса конечно. Проблем с видимостью из других классов нет. Именно что они разовые, и не хочется, чтоб болтались под рукой.

Comment: Сегодня разовые, а завтра нет. Они приватные, видны только в классе. Не вижу никаких проблем

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, есть такой вариант. Я как раз в Interface делал, что глобальные константы, от которых всё пляшет, названы через _Имя, и оказываются в подвале контекстной менюшки.

Comment: Можете перенести их во вложенный класс